# Replace all occurrence of quotes with \quotes within specific quotes

Tags: javascript, regex, str-replace

I have a string as below:

```
var tst ='[{"body":"Hi Akhil station siate "U" turjunction,- Immedia"},'
         +'{"body":"Hiate "dgt" turjunction,- Immedia"},'
         +'{"body":"Hiate "sd turjunction,- Immedia"}]';
```

I want to replace **"** by **\"**, which is only inside body value

This means the string should become

```
'[{"body":"Hi Akhil station siate \"U\" turjunction,- Immedia"},'
             +'{"body":"Hiate \"dgt\" turjunction,- Immedia"},'
             +'{"body":"Hiate \"sd turjunction,- Immedia"}]'
```

It is better if the solution is done using regex.

> My motive behind is to make it as a valid JSON so that after parsing I can get
>   array of objects with keys as **body** and value as string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some thing try as follow

```
var tst ='{"body":"Hi Akhil station siate "U" turjunction,- Immedia"},'
     +'{"body":"Hiate "dgt" turjunction,- Immedia"},'
     +'{"body":"Hiate "sd turjunction,- Immedia"}';

    tst = tst.replace(/\s("[^"]+?")(?!\})|\s"([^ ]+)/g,function($1)
    {
        if($1.match(/".+"/))
        {
            return $1.replace(/"/g,"\\\"");
        }
        else
        {
            return $1.replace(/"/g,"\\\"");
        }
     });


console.log(tst);
```

[Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/rC4bM8/2)

Comment: friend it givs Immedia\"}' not Immedia"}' at the end

Answer (score 1):

Let the Javascript engine do the work for you.

```
var x = JSON.stringify( tst );
```

Comment: but friend it gives output like following

Comment: ""{\"body\":\"Hi Akhil station siate \"U\" turjunction,- Immedia\",\"body\":\"Hiate \"dgt\" turjunction,- Immedia\",\"body\":\"Hiate \"sd turjunction,- Immedia\"}""

Comment: I just want to replace quotes inside of body tag